# Inductorless DC to DC step up converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, schottky

I'm trying to make a DC to DC boost converter without inductors. Actually, I don't know much about this kind of circuits. I did a research on the net and I found the circuit below. But the problem is I don't understand how it works. Especially that boosting stage makes no sense to me. It's quite complicated to me.

I understand that the TL494 produces PWM, but how about those caps and schottky diodes? And 30 kHz PWM? Isn't it too much for this circuit? Can I make this circuit using PIC microsontroller instead of the TL494? Can anyone please explain that?

[image]

Comment: These look like charge-pump based typologies. The wikipedia article for 'charge pump' and 'voltage multipler' has pretty good analysis.

Comment: That's a lot of fairly sizable capactors; an inductor/transformer-based solution would actually be a lot more compact and a lot more efficient.

Comment: @DaveTweed I know but my teacher says me that I have to build the circuit without inductors..And only in 5 seconds the output will be boosted to 240 volt..I don't know if it's possible..

Comment: The capacities are huge and a costly part of this project, you can reduce them, but output current will reduce too. Another thing you'd have to solve is the fairly low output voltage a microcontroller runs at and the voltage dropped by the diodes. Depending on the output voltage requirement, you can reduce the number of stages.

Comment: Not to drag us too far off topic, but when your teacher says "without inductors" does that also mean "without transformers"?

Comment: @StephenCollings I asked if I can use transformers too but she said no.

Comment: This seems like a rather artificial specification, especially if you need to boost it to 240 volts... How about motors, do they count as inductors? You can use a coupled motor-generator set, which is used for some high power systems (like old subway trains). They are inefficient, but so is this capacitor based silliness.